# Rails: rbenv rehash not working (rbenv-shim exists)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I am trying to rehash rbenv after installing a new gem 
it gives me these error on my ubuntu server

```
 rbenv: cannot rehash: /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim exists
```

however .rbenv-shims doesn't exists

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Might be an [issue with directory permissions @ sstephenson/rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/238#issuecomment-11903292):

> FWIW - I also had this problem, and had to change permissions on the dir where it was checking for the .rbenv-shim... so it could write to the dir, so it stopped complaining.

Also, try:

```sh
rm /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim
```

and run:

```sh
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: how can I change the permissions for that dir ..I am not an ubuntu guy

Comment: try this:  
`chmod o+w /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims` 
or:  
`chmod 777 /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims`

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l /home/deployer/.rbenv/`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66137/discussion-between-rebelshrug-and-remon-amin).

Comment: I had to delete the folder that it was complaining about.